# How to prevent leaving the page until answer accepted from jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {

        $("#dialogsendnotifications").dialog('open');
    });

    $("#dialogsendnotifications").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

So basically what it does is when the user tries to navigate away it pops up the yes no dialog. The troub is that the dialog comes up but it navigates away from the page before the user even gets to choose a button.

Can someone please tell me how to get it to wait until the user has selected an answer?

Comment: I recommend strongly against this.  It is a really bad user experience, and nearly any legitimate business need is better implemented in a different way.  For example avoiding accidental data loss by navigating away is better served by some sort of interim save (possibly autosave draft) feature.  What if they lose their connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The `onbeforeunload` event is very, very restrictive. All you can do is return a string which the *browser* will then use in its own dialog. You can't do anything fancy at all.

Here's an example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ubitew) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ubitew/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(event) {
    return "This is the message you're allowed to provide";
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. For me, this helps:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
 return '';
})
```

But in my example, i have a loop (`.each()`) inside my "beforeunload"-function. Then not forget to exit the loop before you want to return a value ;)

Answer (score -1):

return false to block the action like so:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    $("#dialogsendnotifications").dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is unlike other events. `return false` has no effect on `onbeforeunload` other than to make the browser display its "really leave this page?" dialog with the word "false" in it.

Comment: That's interesting.  Can you say event.preventDefault() to stop it?

Comment: @ robrich: Again, `onbeforeunload` is special. If you look at the jQuery documentation, you'll see that `return false` just means `event.preventDefault();` combined with `event.stopPropagation();`. So no, `event.preventDefault();` won't help.